# unable to post values from external source in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-curl, codeigniter-4

I am trying to Post values using CURL into Codeigniter 4 based App

but i am getting `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded` error.

here i am using code to post from external source

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/add';
$myvars = 'name=hello&description=somedescription';

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

I used the following without curl

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/add';
$data = array('name' => 'value', 'description' => 'value');
$options = array(
        'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
var_dump($result);
```

but none of them working

i gave CSRF Exception in filter.php ([documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html))

```
public $globals = [
        'before' => [
                'csrf' => ['except' => ['api/add']]
        ]
];
```

here is the code in Controllers/Api.php

```
public function add(){
  
   return $_POST['name'] . $_POST['description'];
  
          
}
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: +1 on providing good test code. I have run it on two different sites ( virtual hosts ) and it works or I get an error response. So the issue would be with your "External Source" site. It's doing something funky and PHP has got lost and performed a timeout. So what else is going on with the "External" site ?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw external site is also a CodeIgniter 4 based site.

Comment: It is possible that you might be suffering from a connection timeout. To test that - what happens if you attempt to directly access http://localhost:8080/api/add via your browser or create another method i.e. hello which echoes back a string to test it. What is the response?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw when i access localhost:8080/api/add via browser then it is working fine. and  i created a plain php file and performed executed above CURL code which is working fine. the only thing is not working on codeigniter based sites. nor from same site neither another external site.